# to calculate all rows matching search criteria

Tags: filter, vuejs2

In my Laravel5(v5.5.24)/vue.js2(v2.5.8)/ application I do filter on my page using vue filter, like:

```
    <li  v-for="nextUserChatMessage, index in setFiltertUserChatMessages">

...

            setFiltertUserChatMessages: function () {
                return this.userChatMessages.filter( (user_chat_message) => {
                    var res= user_chat_message.text.match(this.search_text);
                    return res;
                });
```

This filter works ok for me, but I would like to calculate all rows matching search criteria.
If there is a way for this ?
I can increment rows when var res is true with some counter variable, when when to set this counter variable to zero?

Or it can be done in some other way?

Thanks!

Imre_G, thanks for response!
I tried to follow your way:

```
<ul  >
   <li  v-for="nextUserChatMessage, index in setFilterUserChatMessages">
      <div class="col-xs-12 m-10">
         <span class="user_name">{{ nextUserChatMessage.author_name }}</span>,
         <span v-if="nextUserChatMessage.updated_at_label">
         <small>modified at</small> <span class="timestamp_as_ago_label">{{ nextUserChatMessage.updated_at_label }}</span>
      </span>
         <span v-else>
         <span class="timestamp_as_ago_label">{{ nextUserChatMessage.created_at_timestamp | time_since_label }}</span>
         </span>
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <span v-html="nextUserChatMessage.text"></span>
            <!--| highlight-->
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
<br>:
{{ countFilterUserChatMessages }};;;;;



            setFilterUserChatMessages: function () {
                return this.userChatMessages.filter((user_chat_message) => {
                    var res = user_chat_message.text.match(this.search_text);
                    return res;
                });

            },

            countFilterUserChatMessages: function() {
                alert( "countFilterUserChatMessages::"+var_dump(countFilterUserChatMessages) )
                return setFilterUserChatMessages.length
            },
```

But I got an error in console :

```
app.js?dt=1513588403:1297 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: countFilterUserChatMessages is not defined"

found in

---> <UserChatsRun> at resources/assets/js/components/user_chats/UserChatsRun.vue
       <Root>
warn @ app.js?dt=1513588403:1297
logError @ app.js?dt=1513588403:2415
globalHandleError @ app.js?dt=1513588403:2410
handleError @ app.js?dt=1513588403:2399
Vue._render @ app.js?dt=1513588403:5152
updateComponent @ app.js?dt=1513588403:3464
get @ app.js?dt=1513588403:3807
run @ app.js?dt=1513588403:3884
flushSchedulerQueue @ app.js?dt=1513588403:3650
(anonymous) @ app.js?dt=1513588403:2515
flushCallbacks @ app.js?dt=1513588403:2436
Promise resolved (async)
microTimerFunc @ app.js?dt=1513588403:2484
nextTick @ app.js?dt=1513588403:2528
queueWatcher @ app.js?dt=1513588403:3737
update @ app.js?dt=1513588403:3874
notify @ app.js?dt=1513588403:1403
reactiveSetter @ app.js?dt=1513588403:1726
proxySetter @ app.js?dt=1513588403:3965
(anonymous) @ app.js?dt=1513588403:61232
Promise resolved (async)
loadUserChatMessagesList @ app.js?dt=1513588403:61230
boundFn @ app.js?dt=1513588403:911
mounted @ app.js?dt=1513588403:61127
callHook @ app.js?dt=1513588403:3591
insert @ app.js?dt=1513588403:4768
invokeInsertHook @ app.js?dt=1513588403:6529
patch @ app.js?dt=1513588403:6748
Vue._update @ app.js?dt=1513588403:3336
updateComponent @ app.js?dt=1513588403:3464
get @ app.js?dt=1513588403:3807
Watcher @ app.js?dt=1513588403:3796
mountComponent @ app.js?dt=1513588403:3468
Vue$3.$mount @ app.js?dt=1513588403:9054
Vue$3.$mount @ app.js?dt=1513588403:11393
(anonymous) @ app.js?dt=1513588403:12276
__webpack_require__ @ app.js?dt=1513588403:20
Object.defineProperty.value @ app.js?dt=1513588403:26489
__webpack_require__ @ app.js?dt=1513588403:20
__webpack_exports__.d @ app.js?dt=1513588403:63
(anonymous) @ app.js?dt=1513588403:66
11:13:24.646 app.js?dt=1513588403:2419 ReferenceError: countFilterUserChatMessages is not defined
    at VueComponent.<anonymous> (app.js?dt=1513588403:61173)
    at VueComponent.countFilterUserChatMessages (app.js?dt=1513588403:61164)
    at Watcher.get (app.js?dt=1513588403:3807)
    at Watcher.evaluate (app.js?dt=1513588403:3914)
    at VueComponent.computedGetter [as countFilterUserChatMessages] (app.js?dt=1513588403:4165)
    at Object.get (app.js?dt=1513588403:2622)
    at app.js?dt=1513588403:61415
    at Proxy.renderList (app.js?dt=1513588403:4363)
    at Proxy.render (app.js?dt=1513588403:61364)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (app.js?dt=1513588403:5150)
```

But I do not see error in my syntax.
Could you, please, to point at it?

Below is the file:

```
<template>
    <section>
        <div class="form-group pull-right">
            <router-link :to="{name: 'createUserChat'}" class="btn btn-success">Add</router-link>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">User's chats list RUN</div>
            <div v-if="message" class="has_error">
                <center>{{ message }}</center>
            </div>
            <section class="panel-body white-box">

                <div class="alert alert-info" v-if="userChatMessages.length === 0">
                    <span v-if="is_inited">No Data Found</span>
                </div>

                <div v-else class="p-10">
                    <div class="row">

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="search_text" placeholder="Search in this chat"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">

                        <small class="badge float-right"  v-if="typing" :class='badgeClass'>{{ typing }}</small>

                        <ul  >
                            <li  v-for="nextUserChatMessage, index in setFilterUserChatMessages">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 m-10" v-bind:style="{ 'color':nextUserChatMessage.userProfileValuesArray.color,
                                     'background-color':nextUserChatMessage.userProfileValuesArray.background_color }"  >
                                    user_id::{{ nextUserChatMessage.user_id }},
                                    <span class="user_name" >{{
                                        nextUserChatMessage.author_name }}</span>,
                                    <span v-if="nextUserChatMessage.updated_at_label">
                                    <small>modified at</small> <span class="timestamp_as_ago_label">{{ nextUserChatMessage.updated_at_label }}</span>
                                </span>
                                    <span v-else>
                                    <span class="timestamp_as_ago_label">{{ nextUserChatMessage.created_at_timestamp | time_since_label }}</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <span v-html="nextUserChatMessage.text"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        {{ countFilterUserChatMessages }}
                        <div v-if="submit_message_by_enter" class="p-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message here and press Enter key" v-model="user_chat_new_message"
                                   @keyup.enter='sendNewMessage'>
                        </div>
                        <div v-else class="p-10">
                            <textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message here and press 'Send' button" v-model="user_chat_new_message"></textarea>
                            <div class="p-t-10">
                                <a @click='sendNewMessage' class="btn btn-success">Send</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    import { bus } from '../../app';

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                user_chat_new_message: '',
                userChatMessages: [],
                message: '',
                is_inited: '',
                appHandling: {},

                chat: {
                    message: [],
                    user: [],
                    color: [],
                    time: []
                },
                typing : '',
                search_text : '',
                submit_message_by_enter : true
            }
        },  // data: function () {

        created() {
            this.appHandling= new AppHandling(this);
            this.app_bus= bus
            this.submit_message_by_enter= user_profile_submit_message_by_enter == "Y"
            bus.$on('newUserChatAddedEvent', (event) => {
                this.userChatMessages.push( {'author_name': event.author_name, 'text': nl2br(event.text), 'created_at_timestamp': this.getNowDateTime()} )
            })
        },

        mounted() {
            var app = this;
            app.loadUserChatMessagesList(app)
            app.is_inited = true

        }, // mounted() {

        computed:{
            setFilterUserChatMessages: function () {
                return this.userChatMessages.filter((user_chat_message) => {
                    var res = user_chat_message.text.match(this.search_text);
                    return res;
                });
            },

            countFilterUserChatMessages: function() {
                return setFilterUserChatMessages.length
            },

        },


        methods: {
            sendNewMessage() {
                if (this.user_chat_new_message.length > 0) {
                    console.log(this.user_chat_new_message)
                    this.app_bus.$emit('newUserChatAddedEvent', {'author_name': 'you', 'text': nl2br(this.user_chat_new_message), 'created_at_timestamp': this.getNowDateTime()} );
                    axios.post(window.API_VERSION_LINK + '/send', {
                        message: this.user_chat_new_message
                    })
                        .then(function (response) {
                            app.errorsList= {};
                            app.userChatMessages = response.data.userChatMessagesList;
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            alert("error::" + var_dump(error))
                            console.log(error);
                            app = app.appHandling.rowEditorClientError(error);
                        });

                    this.user_chat_new_message = ''
                }
            }, // sendNewMessage() {

            loadUserChatMessagesList(app, page, order_by, order_direction) {
                app.message = '';
                if (typeof page == "undefined") page = 1;
                if (typeof order_by == "undefined") order_by = "name";
                if (typeof order_direction == "undefined") order_direction = "asc";

                var user_chat_id = 1
                axios.get(window.API_VERSION_LINK + '/user_chat_run?id=' + user_chat_id + "&page=" + page + "&order_by=" + order_by + "&order_direction=" + order_direction)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        app.userChatMessages = response.data.userChatMessagesList;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        app = app.appHandling.rowEditorClientError(error);
                    });
            }, // loadUserChatMessagesList(app, page, order_by, order_direction) {

            removeUserChat(id, user_chat_name, index) {
                var app = this;
                app.message = '';
            }, // removeUserChat(id, user_chat_name, index) {

        }, // methods: {

    }


</script>
```

Comment: Could you add your component structure? So with the <template> and <script> parts?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using a computed variable for setFiltertUserChatMessages the easiest way is to have a second computed variable which looks like this:

```
computed: {
        setFiltertUserChatMessages () {
            return this.userChatMessages.filter( (user_chat_message) => {
                var res= user_chat_message.text.match(this.search_text);
                return res;
            })
        },
        countFiltertUserChatMessages () {
            return setFiltertUserChatMessages.length
        }
}
```